# RIP tool has weird outline

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

[image]

Hi I'm new to Blender.
After I used the rip tool(v), it left an outline in my model and I cannot remove it. I tried highlighting using "b", deleted the whole object, it's still there

Comment: are you in vertex select mode?

Comment: yes, I also changed in edge and face select modes. I still can't select the line